# Ubuntu 20.04 Hibernate logging me out and doesn't work

Tags: partitioning, grub2, 20.04, swap, hibernate

I am new here and I switched from Win10 to Ubuntu a couple of days ago. I am having an issue with Ubuntu. I am unable to hibernate using `sudo systemctl hibernate`,`sudo hibernate` or `sudo pm-hibernate` . I have tried various tutorials and How TOs but no success so far.

My Ubuntu version is Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Kernel: Linux 5.4.0-42-generic

Architecture: x86-64

GNOME version: 3.36.3

Secure Boot = Disabled

I am using HP 255 G7 Notebook PC.

The main problem is when I execute `sudo systemctl hibernate`, my screen goes blank, turns off for 2-3 seconds, logs me off and turn on again and asks for account password.

**The things I have performed**:

I had a swapfile by default when I installed my OS. But I removed it and created a swap partition instead using GParted for some reason.
Then I executed the following commands:

`sudo apt install pm-utils hibernate` =>(Done Successfully!)

`cat /sys/power/state` =>(freeze mem disk)

`grep swap /etc/fstab`=>(no output)

As `grep swap /etc/fstab` was not doing any output, I edited the file `/etc/fstab` and added the UUID of my swap partition manually (that was the most suspicious and silly part I guess). Now my /etc/fstab looks like:

```
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=e05ff4f8-84f6-4f85-95ae-9180539bf7a1 /               ext4    errors=remoun>
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=2E2D-5430  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1

UUID=d8829268-901e-4c50-b99e-b75bfd08261b swap           swap    defaults   0 2
```

`d8829268-901e-4c50-b99e-b75bfd08261b` is my swap partition's UUID (found via GParted).

The next command I executed is:
`sudo nano /etc/default/grub`.
After editing the file looks like:

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
# info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash resume=UUID=d8829268-901e-4c50-b99e-b7>
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"
# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console
```

After saving the file, I did:

`sudo update-grub` => (Done Successfully).
At last when I executed:
`sudo systemctl hibernate`

My system logged out, screen went off for 2-3 sec, screen turned ON again asking for user-password.

Please help me out, I am really stuck here. Huge Thanks

Comment: There's a good reason Ubuntu ships with hibernate disabled by default. As you've discovered, it's super unreliable, and very hardware specific. Just saying that to set your expectations accordingly.

Comment: @popey Do you mean that it could be a hardware specific problem? Hibernation was working perfectly alright in Win10. So it could be a driver issue?

Comment: Ubuntu isn't Windows. It's entirely possible (and likely) that hibernate works well in Windows, but not in Ubuntu. Hibernate on Linux in general has always been somewhat unreliable, which is one reason why it's not enabled on Ubuntu. My point is merely that you should set your expectations for hibernate to work well on Linux a bit lower ;)